# Getting property from unknown interface

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface, ienumerable

I have two interfaces `IndexField` and `BatchField`. **They do not share the same base class**. Both of them have a `Name` Property. So given this method

```
private void Initialize(IEnumerable fields)
{
    List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (object fld in fields)
    {
        string name = string.Empty;

        if (fld is IndexField indexField)
        {
            name = indexField.Name;
        }
        else if (fld is BatchField batchField)
        {
            name = batchField.Name;
        }

        fieldNames.Add(name);
    }

    // Do something ...
}
```

I pass in a collection of `batchfields` or `indexfields` as a parameter. I want to assign the name property to a new list of strings.

I know I can pass in `List<string> fieldNames` as a method parameter but my question is:

Is there a way that I can avoid the if statements and call the `Name` property although I don't know the correct interface type?

I started with this code and thought it would be a good one but maybe there is something like

```
List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>();

foreach (object fld in fields)
{
    fieldNames.Add(fld.Name); // fld might be an IndexField or BatchField interface
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make overloads for your method?

Comment: In your last foreach statement, you can't access the `Name` property, because the `fld` is an object type. Why don't create another interface and inherit this both interfaces from it and then change the `fld` type in your last `foreach` from `object` to that newly created interface?

Comment: Can you change the `IndexField` and `BatchField` interfaces? If so, have them implement a new interface (`INameable`) with a single string property called `Name` and you are good to go... BTW, c# naming conventions is to start the name of an interface with a capital `I`, so while you're at it, you might also want to rename them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting a property with Reflection:

```
private object GetPropertyValue(object item, string property)
{
    // No value
    object value = null;

    var pi = item.GetType().GetProperty(property);

    // If we have a valid property, get the value
    if (pi != null)
        value = pi.GetValue(item, null);

    // Done
    return value;
}
```

Here's how to implement it:

```
private void Initialize(IEnumerable fields)
{
    List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (object fld in fields)
    {
        string name = GetPropertyValue(fld, "Name").ToString();
        fieldNames.Add(name);
    }

    // Do something ...
}
```

I was unable to test your code so you might need to tweak it.

Using Reflection here is probably bad practice. You should probably either fix your interfaces or create overloads for your method.

Answer (score 3):

And another one liner using linq:

```
fieldNames.AddRange(
     fields.Select(obj => (obj as IndexField)?.Name ?? (obj as BatchField)?.Name));
```

[See a live demo on .Net fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bM8KdV)

Though Ideally you should change `IndexField` and `BatchField` to implement a common interface as I wrote in the comments to the question.

Comment: This would add null entries, if there are other types than A and B in the list, so should also add .Where(s => s != null), or actually the op had empty strings if they was not A or B so  adding "?? string.empty" should do.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen or if the `Name` property is null in the object - so I'm kind of reluctant to handle nulls here.

Answer (score 1):

How about just simply using

```
var fieldNames = fields.OfType<IndexField>().Select(i => i.Name)
    .Union(fields.OfType<BatchField>().Select(b => b.Name))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your last `foreach` statement, you can't access the `Name` property, because the `fld` is an object type. You can create another `interface` and inherit your both `interfaces` from it and then change the `fld` type in your last `foreach` from `object` to that newly created interface. Something like this:

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
    String Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IndexField: IBaseInterface
{        
}

public interface BatchField: IBaseInterface
{
}
```

And then:

```
foreach (BaseInterface fld in fields)
{
    fieldNames.Add(fld.Name); 
}
```

Or even simpler with LINQ:

```
List<string> fieldNames = (from IBaseInterface fld in fields select fld.Name).ToList();
```